# Grouping variable must be a vector Error in KNN Classifier

Tags: matlab, classification, knn

I am working on KNN classifier using matlab's function：

```
knnclassify(gp,trainingClass, gpTest),
```

where

`gp` is  `<849x36 double>` matrix , `gpTest` is matrix to test but it raises the following error

> Error using grp2idx (line 39) Grouping variable must be a vector or a
>   character array.
>
> Error in knnclassify (line 81) [gindex,groups] = grp2idx(group);
>
> Error in test (line 1) knnclassify(gp,trainingClass, gpTest);

Answer (score 0):

The error is fairly clear - the `gpTest` variable should be a vector with the same length as the training data (`trainingClass`) containing a group label describing each training sample. This can be either numeric or a character array.

To clarify this, `knnclassify` (in its simplest form) is defined as

```
CLASS = knnclassify(SAMPLE,TRAINING,GROUP)
```

Where `SAMPLE` contains the *n* points that you want to classify based on the *m* training samples in `TRAINING`, each of which are defined as belonging to a class given in `GROUP`. The classifier will then predict the class of each of the *n* samples in `SAMPLE` based on the *k* nearest neighbours in the training data in `TRAINING`. `SAMPLE` and `TRAINING` should contain the same number of columns. By default, *k* is 1, so it will classify each point based on the nearest training sample using the Euclidean distance.